# ubuntu: Installed php-mcrypt but it doesn't show up in phpinfo()

Tags: php, nginx, mcrypt

A web app I'm trying to install on my ubuntu 10.04 LTS requires mcrypt, and is generating this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open(). I know this is the same question as this one: [Installed php-mcrypt but it doesn't show up in phpinfo()](https://serverfault.com/questions/234288/installed-php-mcrypt-but-it-doesnt-show-up-in-phpinfo), but I tried several things, none of which worked, and have additional questions. I would comment on the original thread but don't have enough reputation to do so; forgive me for the duplicate question.

My versions of php and mcrypt are (both installed via apt-get):

```
php: 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10
mcrypt: 5.3.2-0ubuntu
```

Doing a `php -m` shows that the `mcrypt` module is installed. I installed `mcrypt` and `php5-mcrypt` via `apt-get`.

Also, I'm using `nginx` as my web server. I have tried reinstalling mcrypt and restarting nginx, but still can't get mcrypt to show up on phpinfo() and calls to mcrypt are still broken.

Here is some more info:

```
$ php -i | grep "mcrypt"
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini,
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
```

I also checked that mcrypt is on in `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini` and `/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/mcrypt.ini`.

Lastly, I'm using fastCGI with nginx. I googled around and saw suggestions to restart php5-fpm. I couldn't find php5-fpm in apt-get, I'm not sure if I still need php5-fpm since I already have fastCGI.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Just reboot your machine.

Comment: Why on earth would he reboot his machine? He just has to restart the PHP process... (not nginx)

Comment: Rebooting the machine actually worked. How could I have restarted the PHP processes without rebooting?

Comment: Nevermind my question, nginx has a script here to start and stop fastCgi: http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample

Answer (score 1):

PHP-FPM is the fastcgi process manager (or something like that); it is a common way of keeping PHP processes alive while nginx restarts.

From the command line, `ps aux` will show you what's running; if this is a private / testing server, `sudo kill <process id>` on anything that has PHP in the name until all the old processes are dead (or as commented above, reboot the whole box); if it's a public / live server you may not want to be so reckless...

Also, `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini` -- what about `/etc/php/cgi/...` if that exists?

Comment: `/etc/php/cgi/...` doesn't exist, actually. Does this mean I'm missing something?

When I do `ps aux`, I see 15+ instances of `/usr/bin/php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000` run by nginx. Is it safe to kill all of these?